# R subsetting data frame misses rows

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Last november I asked a question about subsetting data from two different data frames ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566739/r-selecting-column-in-a-data-frame-by-column-in-another-data-frame)). I wanted to select rows from data1 that had same latitude as the desired row from data2. Now I am having not the same but a similar problem.

My data files have this structure:

Data file

```
date time stat_id lat lon tempc
20121122 0 1 0.407353E+02 -0.165700E+00 0.798737E+01
20121122 0 2 0.406287E+02 -0.113300E+00 0.649903E+01
20121122 0 3 0.406621E+02 -0.209800E+00 0.772955E+01
20121122 0 4 0.403943E+02 -0.126100E+00 0.798837E+01
20121122 0 5 0.404532E+02 0.604000E-01 0.103548E+02
```

Places file

```
Zona Poble   stat_id     lat lon     alt
1 Zorita             1   0.407353E+02 -0.165700E+00  691.867004
1 Morella    2   0.406287E+02 -0.113300E+00  955.718994
1 Forcall    3   0.406621E+02 -0.209800E+00  753.882019
2 Benasal    4   0.403943E+02 -0.126100E+00  848.171021
2 Cati           5   0.404532E+02 0.604000E-01   667.609985
```

They both share stat_id field. I want to subset data file depending on places$Zona. As an example, if I want Zona to be 1 then three places are to be extracted, stat_id=1,2,3. For subsetting I use this command:

```
zona1=subset(data,data$stat_id == places$stat_id[places$Zona == 1])
```

This succesfully selects rows in data file for the three stations but not all rows where stat_id is 1,2 or 3. Data file contains hourly data but zona1 just show data for time 0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24 hours. When issuing the command I get this warnings:

```
Mensajes de aviso perdidos
In data$stat_id == places$stat_id[places$Zona == 1] :
  larger object length is not a multiple of the smaller one
```

(excuse my translation of the warning message)

zona1 output is

```
"","date","time","stat_id","lat","lon","tempc"
"1",20121122,0,1,40.7353,-0.1657,7.98737
"2",20121122,0,2,40.6287,-0.1133,6.49903
"3",20121122,0,3,40.6621,-0.2098,7.72955
"385",20121122,30000,1,40.7353,-0.1657,7.00632
"386",20121122,30000,2,40.6287,-0.1133,4.83684
"387",20121122,30000,3,40.6621,-0.2098,6.42246
"769",20121122,60000,1,40.7353,-0.1657,6.55283
"770",20121122,60000,2,40.6287,-0.1133,4.85467
"771",20121122,60000,3,40.6621,-0.2098,5.90663
"1153",20121122,90000,1,40.7353,-0.1657,6.35216
"1154",20121122,90000,2,40.6287,-0.1133,5.66342
"1155",20121122,90000,3,40.6621,-0.2098,6.15894
```

This is the script I'm trying:

```
datos=read.table("data.dat",header=T)
pobles=read.table("pobles-zona.dat",header=T)

data=as.data.frame(datos)
places=as.data.frame(pobles)

zona1=subset(data,data$stat_id == places$stat_id[places$Zona == 1])
```

and data files available at

[data.dat](http://ubuntuone.com/0pDaVxaBQZWZSAVr2b3n6v) http://ubuntuone.com/0pDaVxaBQZWZSAVr2b3n6v

[pobles-zona.dat](http://ubuntuone.com/753L9uFbntRc46Ah5gIZdp) http://ubuntuone.com/753L9uFbntRc46Ah5gIZdp

I should be missing something, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a guess, but I'd say that missing values are tripping you up. See what happens if you replace `stat_id == places$stat_id` with `stat_id %in% places$stat_id`. (`%in%` ignores NAs rather than propagating them.)

Comment: It works!! Thanks @HongOoi It runs fine now, but why? There are no NAs in data file.

Comment: @pacomet I suspect it's not "NA" here but the fact that `data$stat_id` is not the same length as `places$stat_id[places$Zona == 1]` , so the test of equality recycles the shorter one, which is not what you want.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft This is a good point. places is 128 rows/stations but data is 128x73 rows. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been solved with the comment by Hong Ooi. It just was replacing == by %in%

The rigth one was

```
zona1=subset(data,data$stat_id %in% places$stat_id[places$Zona == 1])
```

Thanks Hong and Carl